# Size of an element in CSS3: error in Adam Freeman's book?

Tags: html, css, height

I'm reading the book of Adam Freeman "The Definitive Guide to HTML5".
At page 503, regarding "Controlling the size of an element", the book reads:
"You can specify sizes explicitly using lengths or percentages. The percentage values are calculated from the width of the containing block (**even when dealing with height**)"
It refers to the height and width of a css box.

I think that there is an error. Isn't the height of a box computed with respect to the height of the containing box when using percentage?
I know that only padding and margin are always computed with respect to the width of the container, even when dealing with vertical margins or padding.

Am I wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: When you have a doubt, the only reliable source where there is no mistake is the Specification: https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#the-height-property ... you can find error everywhere but rarely in the Spec (probably never)

Comment: @Paulie_D thanks. The specific problem is: how to set the height of a box (in terms of CSS's box model), as for instance a div, using the percentage. The percentage in CSS is related to some other measures (for instance the width of the parent's box). Therefore, it seems strange to me that the height of a box depends on the width of the container, rather than the height of the container.

Comment: Thanks @TemaniAfif, I've looked at the specification and indeed it seems that when using the percentage for the height, it refers to the parent's height. Therefore I think there is an error in the book. I've asked just because I was not sure of this, and it seems strange to me because the book is very well written and largely adopted also in Universities as textbook, but I haven't found any errata or comment regarding this issue.